# open SQLite in mac by double click cause error

Tags: sql, macos, sqlite

My mac is 10.9.4 and I download SQLite today in SQLite Download Page."Precompiled Binaries for Mac OS X (x86)"

If I open SQLite3 by double clicking,
when I try use .read to read a sql file, it appears a blank line.

But if I open it by typing "sqlite3" in terminal,
.read words fine.

So why there is a difference? How to fix the double clicking opening problem?

The sql file is as simple as:

```
drop table if exists T;
create table T (A text, B text);
insert into T values ('Hello,', 'world!');
select * from T;
```